# Display a Week View for a Calendar in angular using Moment from Scratch

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, momentjs

I am trying to recreate a weeks calendar display in angular using moment js from scratch. I would like to display my output as shown in the below image

[image]

On clicking the chevron right button it should display the November next week ie week-2 and on clicking the chevron left button it should display the last week of October. This is what I am trying to do it from scratch. I had done with displaying the next week and the previous week.

EDIT:
My code works fine but I want only November month dates to be displayed in the November month week display but I am getting Start of December dates too. And I want the weekend to be displayed in grey colour.
Can anyone help me how to resolve?

EDIT:
appcomponent.ts file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   moments = extendMoment(moment);
   datevalue:any;
   days = [];
   date = moment();
   weekno = Math.ceil(this.date.date() / 7);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getweeks(this.date);
   
  }
nextweek()
{
  this.date.add(1, 'weeks');
  this.getweeks(this.date);
  console.log('Week No:'+Math.ceil(this.date.date() / 7) );
}
previousweek()
{
  this.date.subtract(1,'weeks');
  this.getweeks(this.date);
}
public getweeks(currentDate)
{
  //var currentDate = moment();
  this.days=[];
  this.weekno = Math.ceil(this.date.date() / 7);
    var weekStart = currentDate.clone().startOf('week');
    var weekEnd = currentDate.clone().endOf('week');

    
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

        this.days.push(moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("ddd[\r\n]DD"));
    };
    console.log('days'+this.days);
}
```

appcomponent.html

```
<div class="flex-container flex-center">
    <div class="row" style="align-items: center!important;">
      <div class="col-1 mr-3">
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          matTooltip="Previous Week"
          [matTooltipPosition]="'above'"
          class="iconsSize ml-1 my-auto"
          (click)="previousweek()"
        >
          <mat-icon>
            chevron_left
          </mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mr-0 pr-0 mt-2">
      <p><b>{{date.format('MMMM ')}}{{date.format('YYYY ')}} Week-{{weekno}}</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pl-0">
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        matTooltip="Next Week"
        [matTooltipPosition]="'above'"
        class="iconsSize ml-0 my-auto"
        (click)="nextweek()"
      >
        <mat-icon class="pl-0 ml-0">
          chevron_right
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center pl-0 pt-2" *ngFor="let day of days">
            <div class="weekday pl-0 pb-2" id="pre">
                {{day}}
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just make an array of all the dates in the year, then create a pagination service/pipe that only displays 7 at a time. Then you could use an ng-for to display those 7 based on the start of week (monday or sunday). From there you could just detect on a pagination change if they're close to the end of the array and then either prepend/append dates as needed.

Comment: I am not suppose to do like it but I want to use of moment js to display week view for the calendar display.

Comment: You can use momentJs - I've done this with moment-timezones with a scrolling calendar in angular. You can use the method above to simply make 3 weeks at a time - take today, find start of the week, then get the previous and the future week. The issue with what you've got above is if a month doesn't start on a Sunday then the calendar would be off, b/c of this it's best to reference it off of the current day and then use moments API to get the start of the week for your first day and work from there.

Comment: I had done using momet js and edited my code here but I am facing a problem here in my above code is I want only the November Month date to be displayed in Week Calendar display of Nov, but I am getting the start dates of December too in my code. Can you help me in this

Comment: My best guess is b/c you're setting `date = moment();` - simply creating a moment like this makes it based on your specific location/today. Since we're now into December it's likely that your initial date is picking up those December dates.